# git cannot push to the remote branch other than master

Tags: git

I have a git question:

in the remote repository, there are two branches: develop master

```
$ git ls-remote --heads origin
1f74f13bfabc3e5765e33ccde9c8c6556f25592e        refs/heads/develop
1f74f13bfabc3e5765e33ccde9c8c6556f25592e        refs/heads/master
```

in my local:

```
git fetch origin develop

git checkout -b test origin/develop
```

in my test branch, I did some commits. Then I want to push back to the develop branch:

```
$ git push origin develop
error: src refspec develop does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://***.git'
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checkout --track` makes branch to follow remote branch and switch immediately. I think `git pull` is better before doing this.

```
git pull
git checkout --track origin/develop
```

And, You make some modification. and push that like this.

```
git push origin develop
```

By the way, Make new branch for local your job if you want new named branch for origin/develop.

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b test
```

After You commit something, merge that to develop branch.

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git merge test
```

But, You have to resolve if there is conflict because somebody will commit new while you are doing some job.
And, Finally you can push your commit to remote branch.

```
git push origin develop
```

Answer (score 0):

> git checkout -b test origin/develop

You created local branch `test` but tried to push `develop`:

> git push origin develop

Push local `test` to remote `develop`:

```
git push origin test:develop
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But it will push all the local commits to the remote.

Comment: Certainly. `git` synchronizes all commits for every fetched/pushed branch.

Comment: @phd Do you mean that it happens after `push`? By the way, why do you want differrent local branch name from remote branch name? I think it's inconvenient.

Comment: On fetch/pull/push. It's not me, see the original question.